# Rails - Unable to autoload constant - Transaction Express API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, autoload

I am new to writing code to support 3rd-party (Transaction Express) API calls for an application that I'm developing. I have been following the tutorial here: https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/integrating-a-third-party-api-with-rails-5-134f960ddbba and it's making sense to me. I am, however, receiving the following error when trying to view subscribers based on the tutorial code.

Error Received:

> Unable to autoload constant Base, expected
>   /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Documents/projects/phrayme/xxxxxxxxxxx/app/services/base.rb
>   to define it

From my research, I think it may be related to the directory structure and what Rails is expecting to be there, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem. Please advise.

subscribers_controller.rb

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @subscribers, @errors = Transexp::Subscriber.random(query)
   end

   def show
     @subscriber = Transexp::Subscriber.find(params[:id])
   end

private

   def query
     params.fetch(:query, {})
   end
end
```

services/base.rb

```
module Transexp
  class Base
    attr_accessor :errors

    def initialize(args = {})
      args.each do |name, value|
        attr_name = name.to_s.underscore
        send("#{attr_name}=", value) if respond_to?("#{attr_name}=")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

services/subscriber.rb

```
module Transexp
  class Subscriber < Base
    attr_accessor :firstName,
                  :lastName,
                  :fullName,
                  :coName,
                  :phone_type,
                  :phone_nr,
                  :addrLn1,
                  :addrLn2,
                  :city,
                  :state,
                  :zipCode,
                  :ctry,
                  :email,
                  :type,
                  :stat,
                  :note

    MAX_LIMIT = 25

    def self.find(id)
      response = Request.get("subscribers/#{id}/information")
      Subscriber.new(response)
    end

    def self.random(query = {})
      response = Request.where('subscribers/random', query.merge({ number: MAX_LIMIT }))
      subscribers = response.fetch('subscribers', []).map { |subscriber| Subscriber.new(subscriber) }
      [ subscribers, response[:errors] ]
    end

    def initialize(args = {})
      super(args)
    end
  end
end
```

view/subscribers/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Subscribers#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/subscribers/index.html.erb</p>

<%= @subscribers %>
```

lib/transexp/request.rb

```
class Request
  class << self
    def where(resource_path, query = {}, options = {})
      response, status = get_json(resource_path, query)
      status == 200 ? response : errors(response)
    end

    def get(id)
      response, status = get_json(id)
      status == 200 ? response : errors(response)
    end

    def errors(response)
      error = { errors: { status: response["status"], message: response["message"] } }
      response.merge(error)
    end

    def get_json(root_path, query = {})
      query_string = query.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
      path = query.empty?? root_path : "#{root_path}?#{query_string}"
      response = api.get(path)
      [JSON.parse(response.body), response.status]
    end

    def api
      Connection.api
    end
  end
end
```

lib/transexp/connection.rb

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

module Transexp
  class Connection
    BASE = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx'

    def self.api
      Faraday.new(url: BASE) do |faraday|
        faraday.response :logger
        faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
        faraday.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        faraday.headers['Gateway_ID'] = ENV['XXXXX']
        faraday.headers['HostedKey'] = ENV['XXXXX']
        faraday.headers['RURL'] = 'https://XXXXX.com/'
        faraday.headers['CURL'] = 'https://XXXXX.com/'

      end
    end
  end
```

end

Thanks for any advice or tips you may provide.

ds

Comment: the directory tree has to match the namespace, so put your base.rb in a subdirectory `/services/transexp/base.rb`

Comment: thanks Ahmad... implemented your suggestion, now getting similar error pointing to other file that exists (Unable to autoload constant Transexp::Request, expected /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Documents/projects/phrayme/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lib/transexp/request.rb to define it). I've verified the existence of that request.rb file.

Comment: can you post the content and directory of that file? it's probably the same error, you just need to make sure that the namespace matches the tree directory.

Comment: lib/transexp/request.rb added to body (above) of question. Thanks again for your help Ahmad.

Comment: it should be ```module Transexp
  class request
  end
end``` , you're missing the namespace.

Comment: remember, the directory tree has to match the namespace, either put the module Transexp on top of your request class (just like subscriber), or keep the request class as it is, and put it directly inside the lib folder, no need for `transexp` subdirectory. hope that makes sense

Comment: Understood. I've added the 'module Tranexp...' code and it appears to be working. However, now get this error: "undefined method `map' for <ActionController::Parameters {"number"=>25} permitted: false>:ActionController::Parameters Did you mean? tap" pointing to line 19 of request.rb ... this is referring to code from that tutorial I'm following. Any tips to get around this too?

Comment: yes because you need to convert `query` to hash first, `query.to_unsafe_h.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")`

Comment: Thanks again Ahmad. That seems to help also. Looks like I should probably find a better tutorial because there are more errors. Any recommendations regarding building an API client?

Comment: not sure what's out there. I'd say follow it to the end, just google the errors and you will find answers.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. One last question for you.... now just getting a "uninitialized constant Connection" error, referring to the end of that request.rb file. Is that also related to expected Rails convention not being met?

Comment: in your request.rb, it should be `Transexp::Connection.api`, when you call a class, you call the entire namespace from top down.

Comment: That works. Thanks again for your expertise. I appreciate your time.